# Condition which implies that finitely generated subgroups of a finitely generated group have fewer generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

I'm still working on quandles, and have made some progress. I now want to understand finitely generated things. To this end, I want to, again, consider finitely generated groups. Let $G$ be a finitely generated group, and let $H\leq G$. I know that it's possible for $H$ to have more generators than $G$ does, for instance, in the case of the finitely generated free group. Are there any natural conditions one might put on $G$ to guarantee that a $H\leq G$ has fewer generators than $G$ does? This would naturally delete the class of free groups from consideration.

Comment: Finitely generated abelian groups. But it's not true even for nilpotent groups (even class two) so I doubt it goes much further than that.

Comment: By the way, you are talking about the "rank of $G$", which is the least size of a generating set for $G$. You are asking for classes in which $H\leq G \implies \mathrm{rk}(H)\leq\mathrm{rk}(G)$.

Comment: Any finitely generated group $G$ that contains a free subgroup $F<G$ with $\text{rk}(F) \ge 2$ is ruled out, because $F$ itself contains free subgroups of all ranks, including one of rank $> \text{rk}(G)$. And LOTS of groups contain free subgroups of rank $\ge 2$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Do you have a reference for the fact that finitely generated abelian groups have this property?

Comment: Not off the top if my head, but it is easy to verify using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81099/742), and that for any group $G$ and normal subgroup $N$, $\mathrm{rk}(G/N)\leq\mathrm{rk}(G)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I looked at the reference that you sent about free abelian groups. Is the idea that if the argument works for free abelian groups, then it will also work for finitely generated abelian groups?  I'm missing the connection between this and the normal subgroup observation.

Comment: Say $G$ is generated by $k$ elements and $H$ is a subgroup. Then $G$ is a quotient of a free abelian group of rank $k$, $F$, $G\cong F/N$. Then $H$ corresponds to a subgroup $K$ of $F$ that contains $N$, $H\cong K/N$. But $K$ is generated by at most $k$ elements (because subgroups of a free abelian group of rank $k$ can be generated by at most $k$ elements), so $\mathrm{rank}(H) = \mathrm{rank}(K/N)\leq \mathrm{rank}(K)\leq k = \mathrm{rank}(G)$.